# Get list of resources from Azure

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to get some information from a list of resource groups in azure. I have the code below which should grab each resource group and then get the properties listed, but it doesn't seem to be running. I'd like to pip it our to a text or csv file too if possible :)

```
   $list = Get-Content C:\temp\resgroups.txt
    foreach ($list in $lists)
    {
    Get-AzureRmResource | select -Property resourcegroupname,resourcename,kind,subscriptionid | export-csv c:\temp\group-content.csv

    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: tried the below

Comment: $server = Get-Content C:\temp\rgs-pp.txt
foreach ($servers in $server)
{
Get-AzureRmResource | Where {$_.ResourceGroupName –eq "$server"} | `
select -Property resourcegroupname,resourcename,kind,subscriptionid

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = Get-Content C:\temp\resgroups.txt
foreach ($list in $lists)
{
    Get-AzureRmResourceGroup $list | select ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I've tried that this morning and I'm still having the same trouble, returns nothing but the prompt. The variables alone show the txt file so it's reading the text file fine.. any thought :(

Comment: well I have no idea whats in your text file and what you are trying to achieve, but this will iterate over lines in text file and feed them one by one to the `get-azurermresourcegroup`.

Comment: Hi, the text file is just a list of resource groups with no headers or spaces. Sorry probably should have mentioned that earlier.  I've got to work although property values are empty .. further investigation required me thinks .. thanks for your help. :)

Comment: so this should definitely work, just try copy\pasting first line to `get-azurermresourcegroup` and see what it returns. the only problems that could be are: you are not logged in, you are logged into a different subscription or your resource group names are wrong